# Which is better in terms of speed php or plpgsql?

Tags: php, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, plpgsql

I am using php 5.3 and postgresql 9.1

Presently, I am doing DB work "outside" DB in PHP by fetching data from DB and processing the data and finally inserting/updating/deleting in DB, but as I am getting comfortable working with postgresql functions I have started coding in plpgsql.

Now, I would like to know is there any speed difference between the two or I can use which ever I am confortable with.

Also, will the answer be same for higher versions => php 5.5 and postgresql 9.3

Comment: That totally depends on what you actually do. Can you show us the code?

Comment: I guess I will get downvoted for posting that as an answer, so here it is: "It depends!"

Comment: mostly, the calculation part where data is fetched and depending upon certain conditions different type of calculations are done to the data and then inserted/updated to DB.

Comment: @feeela Please elaborate as on what it will depend. Even a general idea will help me.

Comment: It depends on whether it is good idea for your application to rely on a specific DBMS when outsourcing business logic to the DBMS. It also depends on the tasks you are doing. Simple string manipulation or excessive data computing. It also depends on your knowledge on PHP vs. stored procedures in plpgsql. And many more "it depends".  There are just too many unknown factors – your question is not specific enough to give you  useful advice.

Comment: project is data intensive, so lot of number crunching will be done using if else and loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what do you do. PL/pgSQL is optimized for data manipulation - PHP is optimized for html pages production. Some background technology is similar - and speed of basic structures is similar - PHP is significantly faster in string manipulations, but PLpgSQL runs in same address space as PostgreSQL database engine, and use same data types as PostgreSQL database engine, so there is zero overhead from data type conversions and interprocess communications.

Stored procedures has strong opponent and strong defenders - it is any other technology, and if you can use it well, it can serve perfect for small, for large projects. It is good for decomposition - it naturally divide application to presentation (interactive) layer and to data manipulation layer. It is important for data centric applications and less important for presentation centric applications. And opponents agree so, sometimes a stored procedures are necessary from performance reasons.

I disagree with kafsoksilo - debugging, unit testing, maintaining is not any issue - when you have knowledges about this technology - you can use almost all tools, that you know. And plpgsql language is pretty powerful (for data manipulation area) language - well documented with good diagnostic, clean and readable error messages and minimum issues.

Comment: My plan of actions seems to be process all logic from front end in PHP and after processing it there send the final ouput to PL/pgsql where DB related "housekeeping" if any is done and then finalised. So DB related stuff I keep in SP and front end, and as I gain more experience I can then optimise. One favourable point in PHP is (I have only read no idea how useful it is) HHVM which speeds up PHP code by parsing it to bytecode whereas in PL case I guess it has to be *rewritten* in C ( I think)

Comment: Depends what do you do, and where is bottleneck. PLpgSQL should be glue for SQL statements - and then a PLpgSQL's overhead is minimal. On second hand, when you would to do some harder calculation, then C is useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot for giving the much needed heads up, discussions here have given me a lot of food for thought and has cleared lots of confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Plpgsql is faster, as you don't have to fetch the data, process them and then submit a new query. All the process is done internally and it is also precompiled which also boosts performance.

Moreover when the database is on a remote server and not locally, you will have the network roundtrip delay. Sometimes the network roundtrip delay is higher that the time that your whole script needs to run.

For example if you need to execute 10 queries on a slow network, using plpgsql and execute only one would be a great improvement.

If the processing that you are going to perform is fetching large chunks of data, and output a true or false, then plpgsql gain will be even greater.

On the other hand, using plpgsql and putting logic in the database, makes your project a lot more difficult to debug, to fix errors and to unit testing. Also it makes a lot more difficult to change the RDBMS in the future.

My suggestion would be to manipulate the data at php, and use a little plpgsql only when you want to isolate some logic for security or data integrity reasons, or you want to tune your project for the best possible performance (which should be a concern after the first release).

Comment: You forgot one aspect: catching at DBMS side. The advantage of postgres will be greater, if the same query is performed multiple times.

Comment: @JohannesH. with PREPARED STATEMENTs you can got same benefit in client side. Most important is fact, so plpgsql runs in same process as database engine.

Comment: Network latency is definitely a point to be kept in mind, which IMO makes more important to process the data near the point of origin.